# React-native, passing a param through navigation v4 to navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props, react-navigation-v5

I know only a little about to get a param in react-navigation v5, then I'd like to know how I can transform this file "ShowScreen.js v4 into a ShowScreen.js v5

This is my file using react-navigation v4:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Context } from '../../context/BlogContext';

export default function ShowScreen({ navigation }) {
  const { state } = useContext(Context);

  const blogPost = state.find(
    blogPost.id === navigation,getParams('id')
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{blogPost.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

But I know that if I want to use something like the react-navigation v5, I need to change it in a new way because there's no getParam in react-navigation v5, the documentation shows a different way, but I'm not sure how I can use it in my two different screens

This is the screen Context where the param id is located using react-navigation v4:

```
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';

const blogReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'delete_blogpost':
      return state.filter(blogPost => blogPost.id !== action.payload);
    case 'add_blogpost':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999),
          title: `Blog Post #${state.length + 1}`
        }
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const addBlogPost = dispatch => {
  return () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'add_blogpost' });
  };
};
const deleteBlogPost = dispatch => {
  return id => {
    dispatch({ type: 'delete_blogpost', payload: id });
  };
};

export const { Context, Provider } = createDataContext(
  blogReducer,
  { addBlogPost, deleteBlogPost },
  []
);
```

I have no idea what's the right way to send the user from the post with the id generated to the right screen generated with the same id, but I know the state is also not used in react-navigation v5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Navigation 5 has a completely new component-based API. While the main concepts are the same, the API is different, you have multiple options:

1. Reuse code using the old API with minimal changes, you can use [the compatibility layer](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/compatibility).
2. You could watch [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQWFhX-gwJbmmqcP-9zMXBaxQbGKfIJY2) it short and descriptive.
3. Read [the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started), as it is fast and clear.